# Bind event on width change, not height (as resize do both);

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, width

I have next javascript code:

```
   function() {
        $( this ).on( "resize", $special.handler);
    }
```

it works ok but I dont need this to trigger on height change, I need to work it only on a widht change.

So I'm trying to add an if statement inside resize detection and to bind `$special.handler` only if width changes.

Can't find a simple way to do this yet, so would you be so kind to help me find what I'm doing wrong?

For the moment I've ended up with next code

```
 function() {
        var widthBefore = $(this).width();
        $( this ).on( "resize", function() {
            if ($(this).width() != widthBefore) {
                $(this).on( WIDTH CHANGE ONLY, $special.handler);
                widthBefore = $(this).width();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What you have is basically the only way to do it, there are no special events for width only.

Comment: There is no event for width change only. Why don't you run the function when you modify the width of the element?

Comment: Also, are you sure this isn't an XY Problem?

Comment: adeneo, BenM - thanks for your input, I thought I missed something, but seems I didn't ))

Answer (score 0):

There is no width change event but if context has to be maintained this can be used -

```
function() {
        var widthBefore = $(this).width();
        $( this ).on( "resize", function() {
            if ($(this).width() != widthBefore) {
                $.proxy($special.handler,this);
                widthBefore = $(this).width();
            }
        });
    }
```